# Subview not appearing where I want it to come out - Xcode

Tags: xcode

I'm new to XCode and am having trouble getting a subView, when added to the main view, to originate from the bottom whereas the top (which I presume is default).
When I mean top, I don't mean the heir-achy but rather literally top of the screen (where the power button and ear jack of an iphone is).

I have tried to play around with the View -> Origin, and View -> Mode - neither did anything.
I would assume it's the auto-layout but I can't be sure.

Basically, I have a colored mainStoryboard and it   `[self.view addSubView:[[AnotherView alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnotherView" bundle:nil]];`

The AnotherView is just a empty half-sized View.
When it gets added, it keeps appearing from the top. I don't know how to make it come from the bottom.

Do you guys have any insight as to how I might be able to make it come from the bottom?

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 1):

add newView to self.view with the frame

> newView.frame=CGRectMake(0,480,320,200);

and after that animate that view by using below animations.

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp
                             animations:^{

    newView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,320,200);

     } completion:nil];
```

Or you can use

> presentModalViewController: animated:

method